# PHP array crashes

Tags: php, arrays, memory

Not really a PHP programmer, but for some reason I got to fix a few PHP functions that crashes.

The main function checks the contents of a CSV/XML file against the database. Everything is fine as long as the database contains ~100,000 products or less.

If the database contains >100,000 products the PHP function crashes.

For performance reasons, some of the database contents are loaded into an associative array of row objects. The array will contain the same number of objects as there are products in the database.

1) It looks like the function crashes when the array becomes too big. Is there a better way to store the contents of the database than in an associative array?

I know I can just check the database for one product at the time, but that's not going to work for performance reasons.

2) If an array is the only option, how can I increase the amount of memory so I can handle a big array like this.

3) When the PHP function crashes, it simply stops running. No exceptions are thrown.

Is there a way to see what went wrong anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: How about... checking 1000 products at a time?

Comment: Are you sure you've turned on [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting)?

Comment: Also, is it possible you could refactor the function to do whatever it's doing in PHP in the database query language instead? (So insert the contents of the file into a temp table in the database)

Comment: Can't check 1000 products at the time, each product in the CSV/XML file needs to be checked against all the products in the database (does it exist y/n etc.).

Comment: Loading the contents of the file into a temp table could be an option, but that will require quite a bit of refactoring. Would prefer a PHP solution so we don't need to refactor a lot of code.

Comment: if you could show us the code, we could have a look at it and help you. but without - it's hard to debug. though most probably it's a memory problem - and if you don't need all datasets at once, the solution is using a generator instead of an array

Answer (score 0):

By default, the memory limit of PHP is 128M. You can change it like this:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
```

You can also try making a function in your database.

Comment: Memory is currently set to 512M.